# Remove javascript when user navigates to a different subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have an app that loads in JavaScript and CSS files when it initializes; when the user navigates to a different subsite that has different files to load in, the app triggers again and loads in the new JavaScript and CSS files. The app uses the method SPComponentLoader.loadScript/loadCss from the package @microsoft/sp-loader to load in the CSS and JavaScript.

The issue that I am facing is the old JavaScript *is still loaded in*, even though *the app removes the related html DOM elements* (script elements with src attribute pointing at the JavaScript file URL).

What I am looking for, is there a way to remove the old JavaScript that is still loaded in even though the DOM element is removed?

Notes:

- I will not necessarily have control of the JavaScript files and their contents
- This is for modern SharePoint Online.
- Vanilla JavaScript is preferred or capabilities afforded by SharePoint apps
- Would like to **avoid** a full page reload